# Use of だけ or だけで in imperative sentences

Tags: grammar, adverbs

I have seen many examples [here](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91%E3%81%A7-dake-de-meaning/), [here](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91) and [here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/jp/dictionary/japanese-english/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91) of the use of だけ and だけで.

But I am not sure if it can be used in an *imperative sentence* such as "Only read the text (and do not respond to the questions)" or "Only respond to question 1".

本文**だけ**読んでください。

質問 1 **だけ**に回答してください。

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, and the two sentences (you wrote?) are perfectly correct.

Comment: I saw that for the sentence "質問 1 だけに回答してください。", のみ can be used instead of だけ. These two adverbs are similar?